# uWSGI - Production touch-reload git commit

Tags: django, git, service, production-environment, uwsgi

I have an app built on Django/nginx/uWSGI.

I'd like my production server to reload uWSGI whenever the master branch gets modified.

I'm wondering if it would be a good practice to [`touch-reload`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#touch-reload) some git file to achieve this.

```
[uwsgi]
#...
touch-reload = .git/index
```

As I'm also using [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) to automate my deployments, maybe it is preferable to touch the uwsig module instead...

What do you think ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
touch-reload = .git/index
```

Ended up working fine